# ASP.NET show and hide image at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I want to show loading picture when I'll click the button. And after finish my some calculation, make this picture is invisible. How to do it without AJAX and not using [WebMethod]? I know some tricks how to do it with AJAX or PageLoad, but I'm interesting, how to do it in the **different threads**, is it possible?

For example my code:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
            imgLoading.Visible = true;
            lblCount.Visible = false;

            //doing some work
            bool isDone = TProfile.Delete(userId, someData);

            if (isDone)
            {
                imgLoading.Visible = false;
                lblCount.Visible = true;
            }

        BindList(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [OnClientClick](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp) to load an image, and by the time the page will finish the cycle to your server and the page will be reloaded it will disappear.